# Login password for ubuntu, RHEL, any cloud image

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-horizon, openstack-heat

**OpenStack cloud Images**:

There are multiple cloud images which are available at **https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/obtain-images.html**. In order to login to the VMs once those are deployed is either by using `ssh key pair` or `password`. But there are images where the `sshkeypairlogin` is disabled and there is no in-built password by default, then how to login to these VMs where the user have only information on the `user-name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are options to generate the password for the in-built users using `cloud-init`:

**Option-1**: ***Using OpenStack horizon***

If the user is using horizon to launch the instance then for the `post-configuration` by providing the config as:

```
    #cloud-config
    chpasswd:
      list: |
        cloud-user:rhel
        root:rheladmin
      expire: False
```

Here the passwords are generated for `cloud-user` and `root` users of RHEL image. The same is used for any user of any image simply by replacing the user.

**Option-2**: ***Using OpenStack heat template***

Using the openstack heat template by providing the `user-data` as below:

```
heat_template_version: 2015-04-30

description: Launch the RHEL VM with a new password for cloud-user and root user

resources:
  rhel_instance:
    type: OS::Nova::Server
    properties:
      name: 'demo_instance'
      image: '15548f32-fe27-449b-9c7d-9a113ad33778'
      flavor: 'm1.medium'
      availability_zone: zone1
      key_name: 'key1'
      networks:
      - network: '731ba722-68ba-4423-9e5a-a7677d5bdd2d'
      user_data_format: RAW
      user_data: |
        #cloud-config
        chpasswd:
          list: |
            cloud-user:rhel
            root:rheladmin
          expire: False
```

Here the passwords are generated for `cloud-user` and `root` users of RHEL image. The same is used for any user of any image.